# ATI RADEON HD 3600 DRIVER FOR UBUNTU

Tags: ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

does anyone know how to install "ATI RADEON HD 3600" Driver on ubuntu 12.10 , 32bit version ?

where should i download it and how should i install ?

thanks ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proprietary**:

Go [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) and choose the driver.
Once it's downloaded, go in the command line and find where you have the .run file located, and move it to a folder called driver.
Run:

```
cd driver/
unzip *.zip
chmod +x *.run
sudo ./*.run
```

And install it.

Once it's done, `sudo shutodown -r -h now`.
To configure the settings and such, run `amdcccle` preferably as root.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.

Comment: driver directory is "lib/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers" ???

Comment: thanks alot . it was really helpful . i could install it ... but desktop cant be load after driver installation :-S what should i do with that ?