# Desktop doesn't load after installing ATI Driver

Tags: ati, graphics, resolution, monitor

I installed ATI Radeon HD 3650 on Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit using following commands:

```
cd lib/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers
unzip *.zip
chmod +x *.run
sudo ./*.run
```

but after restarting the system, I saw a change in resolution in the login page, and also the desktop didn't load the icons and menu bar after logging in. Actually after logging in, I just have a desktop with nothing but the background wallpaper. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/306043/ati-radeon-hd-3600-driver-for-ubuntu (where i learned to install the driver)

Comment: it was not supposed to be "lib/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers" but folder called "driver" that you were supposed to create yourself and then move the run file there (it was very bad explanation). Plus you were possibly given bad advice. Why did you have to download the driver? Did "Additional drivers" tab suggest proprietary drivers or not?

Comment: you should be able to get to command line if you press "Ctrl + Alt + F3". To uninstall the driver: "cd /usr/share/ati/" and  "sudo ./fglrx-uninstall.sh" - not sure if the uninstall script is still located there but lets hope so.

Comment: Ok , thanks.
 the installed one linux is no more important to me , i'm gonna install it again , but , would you please tell me how to install the driver step by step , using .run file or anything else ?

Comment: Plus , i need to install the driver because many times i had problem of low graphic and in ubuntu ask i found out i have to install the driver .

Comment: Make a fresh install of Ubuntu. When you run into problems (low graphics) then ask a new question where you explain what is happening with your Ubuntu and we'll fix it. The problem might not be in a missing driver. Also drivers topic is too big to explain here and your current question is not about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer the same as this recent question: [What drivers do I need? How do I install them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306080/what-drivers-do-i-need-how-do-i-install-them)

> The problem is that the latest fglrx drivers doesn't support 2XXX -
>   4XXX graphic cards models. Then, the only way I found that may makes
>   the driver working is using fglrx-legacy from this repository:
>   https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx
>
> The command line steps are these:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
> ```
>
> Although, you can install it manually using the official package:
>   http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

If you want to install them with the package from AMD (recommended), you can use this guide: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

Comment: i actually downloaded file from : http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx
and i installed it the way i said , but the problem may be something else ...

Comment: Did you do sudo `aticonfig --initial` before install?

Comment: no :-? did i have to do it before install the driver ? does it really work before installing ?

 would you please tell me how to install the driver step by step , using .run file or anything else ?

thanks

Comment: Sorry, after installing the driver, my bad.

Comment: No problem

no , i didn't . do you think it will work if i do it now ?
was the way i installed it right ?

Comment: I added a tutorial at the end of my answer. Read it carefully.